# Why is this 頼んでたら and not 頼んだら in this sentence?

Tags: conditionals

I've come across this construction before and never not anything of it but after coming across a sentence in a light novel I am reading, やはり俺の青春ラブコメはまちがっている, I started to wonder why this conditional seemed to not be constructed in the usual plain past tense + たら form, but rather the te form + たら. Can anyone explain to me why this is? Perhaps a stylistic effect?

Here is the sentence.

`俺が頼んでたらたぶんあいつ来てくんないよ。`

I don't believe the context to really be of importance here, but I will provide some background. The speaker is saying that if he were the one to ask the girl to play tennis instead of the actual person who asked the girl to play tennis, perhaps she would have rejected the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, not sure if it was just a typo in your question title but the たら form of 頼む would be 頼ん**だ**ら rather than 頼ん**だた**ら.

As to the main point of your question, 頼んでたら is just a contraction of 頼んで**い**たら i.e. the たら form of 頼んでいる. The ている/でいる contraction to てる/でる is one I'm sure you're normally familiar with.